# Ansible: How to show the possible values for a registered variable?

Tags: ansible

I would like to explore the possible values for a variable created with `register:` from a specific module, for example the `file` module.

I'm basically looking for documentation of what the possible values are, similar to the documentation of the parameters you can give when using a module. Is there some way to find it / generate it for a given module?

Note:

The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables) says:

> Use of -v when executing playbooks will show possible values for the results.

I have tested this by running a playbook with `-v` and then inserting a `debug` statement right after. Here's an example output:

```
TASK [postgres : Create file directory] *******************************
ok: [test.medstack.net] => {"changed": false, "gid": 111, "group": "postgres", "mode": "0700", "owner": "postgres", "path": "/foo/bar/", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 105}

TASK [postgres : debug] ********************************************************
ok: [test.medstack.net] => {
    "created_postgres_dir": {
        "changed": false, 
        "diff": {
            "after": {
                "path": "/foo/bar/"
            }, 
            "before": {
                "path": "/foo/bar/"
            }
        }, 
        "gid": 111, 
        "group": "postgres", 
        "mode": "0700", 
        "owner": "postgres", 
        "path": "/foo/bar/", 
        "size": 4096, 
        "state": "directory", 
        "uid": 105
    }
}
```

The output from `-v` mostly but not exactly matches the value of the registered variable. But it only gives the new values, it doesn't completely describe the possible other values.

Answer (score 1):

There are no guaranteed method for that.

Some modules describe return values in the docs (like `copy` module [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html#return-values)).
There are also some [common return values](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/common_return_values.html).

But in most cases you will end up with trial-and-error methods, like calling module and then printing the returned value.

And you always can look into module's (or in some cases action plugin's) sources code.
Searching for `exit_json` and `fail_json` calls will usually bring you close enough to possible return values.